# Java How to self destruct pdf and epub files?

Tags: security, pdf, epub, drm, self-destruction

Can I programatically add a meta data to set the timer for self destruction of pdf and epub documents ? Do I have to pay for that if I do it programatcially ?

Comment: You cannot "destroy" a file like that. At best you can embed something in the file that HINTS to the reader app that the file's expired, but that's it. And then it'd only work in the readers/players that support your hints. Trivial bypass: use a different player. e.g. got a PDF form that doesn't allow it to be saved? Use Foxit reader, which ignores those stupid "security" bits in the PDFs and lets you do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Answering for PDF, you need a DRM solution (digital rights management) like Livecycle from Adobe, and they cost money.

Comment: And even a DRM solution does not *self destruct* but merely controls whether some PDF reader can interpret the file correctly.

Comment: can I build the DRM programmatically ?